# the case is growing

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Mix-and-match COVID vaccines: **the case is growing**, but questions remain
> A slew of studies suggests that mixing vaccines provokes potent immune responses, but scientists still want answers on real-world efficacy and rare side effects.
> Source: [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01805-2)

Does "the case is growing" refer to "the cases of getting vaccinated are increasing"? Or does it refer to "the cases of suffering from COVID-19 are growing"?

Comment: It's not very well written. The word ***case*** in your example is nothing to do with medical cases = ***patients***. The writer means that the arguments supporting some previously minority position re mix-and-max vaccines are becoming more convincing. In context, the case for which support is growing is in fact the argument that mix-and-match vaccines are "good" (the writer implies that originally it was thought that such vaccines wouldn't work well, which may or may not be true; this is "persuasive writing").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither. *Case* is singular and is meant in the legal sense of 'the evidence in favour of' giving people doses of different types of vaccine instead of a repeat dose of the same kind.